# Call method from erb rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have erb file in tencet contoller

```
<td><%= link_to "OK", post_path(post.id), method: :suit %></td>
```

And controller of Post

```
helper_method  :suit

def suit
 @post.suit = true

end
```

And routes

```
resources :posts
```

And I get this error "No route matches [POST] "/posts/77" "

How can I fix it?

How pass an argument?

```
<%= link_to "OK", suit_post_path(post), method: :put %>
```

I want pass object post and get in controller

```
def suit

  @post = params[:post]

  @post.suit = true

  if @post.save
    redirect_to tencet_show_path
  end

end
```

Comment: you have to declare the `suit` method as a collection of `post` controller.

Comment: That's not that easy unfortunately. You have to define new action on the controller, generate new route to that action and create a link usign this route. `method` within a link serves to define a HTTP verb to be used with a request.

Comment: Can you discribe this?

Comment: @user3908457 I guess you better read: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are updating post.suit...

You will have to define the suit route in you config/routes.rb:

```
resources :posts do
  put :suit, on: :member
end
```

Also, you can't have the method be :suit. It must be one of the methods, like post, put, get, etc...

So, in your .erb, you would have:

```
<td><%= link_to "OK", suit_post_path(post.id), method: :put %></td>
```

In the contoller:

```
def suit
  @post.suit = true

  if @post.save
    redirect_to your_desired_path
  else
    render :previous_controller_action
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, its works, but how can I pass an argument to the method?

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you would like to pass through?

Comment: I would create a form to pass the params to the controller. The form doesn't have to be displayed on the page. Could use hidden fields to hide it. Would then use the submit action in place of the link_to to send params to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

So couple of things. Firstly, define a new route:

```
resources :posts do
  post :suit, on: :member
end
```

Your `suit` method is already in place (However I have no idea what it is supposed to do - from the code I would expect it will raise an exception). Note that this is not a helper_method.

Then update your link:

```
<td><%= link_to "OK", suit_post_path(post), method: :post %></td>
```

I expect you will receive TemplateMissing exception at the current stage. If you just want to update your post, then change your `suit` action to:

```
def suit
  @post.update_attributes(suit: true)
  redirect :back
end
```

If you still getting some other exception you are not sure what to do with, you might need to read some Rails books - it is not a framework you can easily learn just by reading an existing code.

Comment: It doesn't working "No route matches [POST] "/posts/77/suit" "

Comment: @user3908457 - You have to restart the server after changing routes.

Answer (score 0):

Method in this case doesn't refer to the controller method but the HTTP method. This is also what is blowing up your route.

Create a custom action

```
def toggle_suit
  @post.suit = true
  render :show
end
```

and update your routes

```
routes :posts do
  post '/suits' => 'posts#toggle_suits', as: :toggle_suit
end
```

finally update your erb

```
<%= link_to '...', toggle_suit_url(post: post), method: :post %>
```

The take away here is that `method: :suit` does not do what you think it does.  It causes link to to create an invisible form where the link is the submit button allowing it to POST to your app.